# Why am I being chastized about not participating when I am?

Tags: bug, stackexchange

I've been waiting for this website for a while and was quite excited to receive the email invitation. I clicked and signed up and have been an active member since. However, I have received two emails from the stackexchange team that say:

> We're hoping you can visit the site and follow through with your commitment to help it grow into a vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.

So....why doesn't it recognize that I'm here?

Comment: I got some similar annoy-o-grams. It appears to have been a combination of a weirdness in SE and my somehow participating under a different account than i'd committed with. Decided to just ignore the automated pestering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your Area51 account is somehow not associated with your W.SE account (but that seems unlikely since you were in the private beta). Maybe the SE staff have set a baseline for participation that is higher than what most of us would consider reasonable. It could be arbitrary, like a given amount of rep or they could just be nagging you to participate or at least visit the site every day (though from what I've seen, you've been pretty active). Or the baseline could be based on participation levels of successful vs. unsuccessful sites.

FWIW, this is the only message containing the word *commitment* that I've received since the site went into beta:

> Thank you for following through on your commitment to Woodworking!
>
> In the 13 days since Woodworking launched, the community has generated
>   157 questions (155 answered!), 363 answers, 236 users, and 115 views
>   per day.
>
> Please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be
>   interested in our community:
>
> http://woodworking.stackexchange.com
>
> We hope you continue to visit this site and help it grow into a
>   vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.
>
> All the best,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team
>
> p.s. Now that you've followed through on your commitment, you can
>   commit to an additional site proposal! Check out the list at
>   http://area51.stackexchange.com.